# Can Unicode conversion errors in SSIS be fixed without using Data conversion

Tags: oracle, unicode, oracle11g, ssis, sqldatatypes

When designing SSIS packages I get the following error

> Column "COLUMN_NAME" cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types.

I know that I can add a data conversion step and manually convert between Unicode and non-Unicode manually. This is impractical in my case since I maintain about 100 packages and each time one of them gets changed I have to redo the mappings.

N.B. I work for a corporate company so I can't **just upgrade**.

Is there a way of fixing this error without using data conversion?

*Environment*

My current setup is as follows.

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
- Oracle client 11.2.0 32 Bit
- Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: Whats your source and destination ?

Comment: *I maintain about 100 packages and each time one of them gets changed I have to redo the mappings* -- This sounds like a perfect use case for meta data driven SSIS package developement via [Biml](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress).

Comment: The other alternative is to change the column type on either the source or the destination to match the other.  This would usually be handled within your staging area before loading into production.  If you can't change the data types, can't move your input to go through a staging area to handle the conversions or start using Biml to output your packages, you're stuck manually updating those 100 packages I'm afraid.

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju Source is Oracle 11.1 database. Destination MSSQL 2012

Comment: I would go with either BIML\Changing the datatype as @iamdave suggested. Update all the staging table columns to nvarchar (so that both varchar and nvarchar can be handled).

Comment: Thanks Srikarmogaliraju and iamdave. We have decided to manually convert the varchars in the MSSQL tables into nvarchars.